# Execute multiple Oracle SQL statements simultaneously

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

I have an Oracle database that has 20 very large tables, each with hundreds of partitions. I can compress a table but it takes over 2 hours. This would mean over 40 hours to complete all 20 tables. I would like to run the partition compression simultaneously (1 per table). Because the partitions are added daily I need a utility to generate the "alter table ..." syntax at the time of the run. So far, all I can think of is to create a SQL for each of the 20 tables and their partitions, then run them in 20 SQLPlus sessions.

Is there a better, more automated way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by compress a table? Is is a one-time job? In case you add frequently new partitions and drop the old ones, you could enable compression just for new partitions. Thus by time all uncompressed partitions will disappear.

Comment: I wrote a [job control object to do this](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/job-control-object.html) a few years ago, though to be honest I haven't looked at it in a long time, partly because [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_SCHEDULER.html) came along and does pretty much everything you need.

Comment: As another thought, you could define an [Information Lifecycle (ILM) policy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/vldbg/ilm-strategy-heatmap-ado.html#GUID-B011D86F-DCDE-4BF5-9C47-24B9650EFCA8) and leave the whole thing to Oracle.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit. Yes it's a one time compression of thousands of partitions. I already compressed the table, so as you said, new partitions will be compressed. However, the partitions are created every day, so I can't wait for years for the partitions to roll off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could submit several jobs, which will - in turn - run your code *simultaneously*. Here's an example:

Test tables - I want to modify ID's datatype to `VARCHAR2(10)`

```
SQL> create table t1 (id varchar2(2));

Table created.

SQL> create table t2 (id varchar2(2));

Table created.

SQL> create table t3 (id varchar2(2));

Table created.
```

A procedure which will utilize `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` and is called from `DBMS_JOB` (see below):

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_exe (par_what in varchar2) is
  2  begin
  3    execute immediate par_what;
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.
```

Create jobs which will run the `ALTER TABLE` simultaneously

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(200);
  3    l_job number;
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select 't1' table_name from dual union all
  6                  select 't2'            from dual union all
  7                  select 't3'            from dual)
  8    loop
  9      l_str := 'alter table ' || cur_r.table_name || ' modify id varchar2(10)';
 10      dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 11      dbms_job.submit(l_job,
 12                      'p_exe(' || chr(39) || l_str || chr(39) ||');',
 13                      sysdate
 14                     );
 15      commit;
 16    end loop;
 17  end;
 18  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Jobs are now running; in a few moments (in my case, as it is a simple one - you'd check that somewhat later), check what's being done:

```
SQL> desc t1;
 Name                    Null?    Type
 ----------------------- -------- ----------------
 ID                               VARCHAR2(10)

SQL> desc t3;
 Name                    Null?    Type
 ----------------------- -------- ----------------
 ID                               VARCHAR2(10)

SQL> desc t3;
 Name                    Null?    Type
 ----------------------- -------- ----------------
 ID                               VARCHAR2(10)

SQL>
```